# Firestore trigger is not being called

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore set up like this:

[image: Firestore tree structure image]

And i call onUpdate as explained in Cloud Firestore triggers docs.

```
functions.firestore.document(`users/{userId}`).onUpdate((change, context) => {
    console.log("it's working")
});
```

I click on button to increase the balance but nothing gets logged (the balance gets increased though.)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might to try using `functions.logger.log` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Cloud Function Trigger, you should see its presence inside your Firebase Console. If it is not there, then it is not being exported which is a requirement for it to being triggered.

`exports.myFunction = functions.firestore...`